# Javascript Filter function, not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, filter

My code is very simple: I'm using the filter to modify one element of the array. I checked that the if state does hit and "sattar" is returned. However, both arrays: person and new_p print:
orignal [ 'ali', 'hassan', 'ameer' ]
changed [ 'ali', 'hassan', 'ameer' ]

What am I missing here?

```js
const person = ["ali", "hassan", "ameer"];
const new_p = person.filter(p => {
    if (p === "hassan") {
        return "sattar"
    }
    return p
})

console.log("orignal", person);
console.log("changed", new_p);
```

Comment: `.filter` doesn't fit this situation because of its inner implementation, pls read about it [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead:

```js
const person = ["ali", "hassan", "ameer"];
const new_p = person.map(p => {
    if (p === "hassan") {
        return "sattar"
    }
    return p
})

console.log("orignal", person);
console.log("changed", new_p);
```

A shorter version:

```js
const person = ["ali", "hassan", "ameer"];
const new_p = person.map(p => p === "hassan" ? "sattar" : p);

console.log("orignal", person);
console.log("changed", new_p);
```

Answer (score 1):

use *.map* instead *.filter*

```
const person = ["ali", "hassan", "ameer"];
const new_p = person.map((p) => {
   if (p == "hassan") {
      return "sattar";
   }
   return p;
})

console.log("orignal", person);
console.log("changed", new_p);
```

Comment: Since you have changed the condition you need to change the behaviour too `if(p !== "hassan") { return p;} return "sattar";`